# How to get the result of a query executed by plpy

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I am working with postgres 9.3 and Python 2.7.

In a plpython function, I want to execute a query that returns a boolean. How can I get the boolean result?

For example:

```
result = plpy.execute('select 1<2 ')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to do this:

```
query="select 1<2 as val;"
result=plpy.execute(query)
if result[0]["val"]: 
   print 'of corse: 1 < 2'
else:
   print 'this will never be printed'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example result should be a list of rows. It's in the [documentation here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpython-database.html)

Comment: yes, the result is a list of rows, we get an element of row by typing result[i]["my_column"]. But when the query returns a boolean, how can we know it is true or false ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something else, but you use any python construct you want to test the truthiness of it, e.g. "x = result[i]["my_column"]; if x is True: pass". You're more likely to get better help if you post what you've already done.

Comment: Thank you yieldsfalsehood, I have just figured out how to do that, please check my answer.